# Logs not printed in Logback- Java Web App

Tags: java, web-applications, logback, tomcat9, logback-classic

I have a Java web app which runs on Tomcat 9, I am testing it on Unix machine.
I am migrating from log4j to logback, but when I run app on Tomcat, I can't see logs appended in proper file.
Those are Maven dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-alpha13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0-alpha13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>
```

That is my logback.xml

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">
   <property name="LOG_FILE" value="myLogFile" />
   <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>${logDir}/${LOG_FILE}.log</file>
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
     <!-- daily rollover -->
     <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
     <!-- keep 30 days' worth of history capped at 3GB total size -->
     <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
     <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
  </rollingPolicy>
  <encoder>
     <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<encoder>
     <pattern>%-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
  <!-- Only log level INFO and above -->
  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
     <level>WARN</level>
  </filter>
</appender>
<root level="INFO">
  <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

And in my Tomcat sh script file, I have this configuration

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DlogDir=/home/logs -Dlogback.configurationFile=/home/app/WEB-INF/logback.xml"
```

I also tried to use -Dlogback.configuration, and I get same result, Application is started properly, but logs are not printed in the log file

Comment: Is there a typo? It should be `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DlogDir=/home/logs
-Dlogback.configurationFile=/home/app/WEB-INF/logback.xml"`
If hiphen is already there please Edit the question

Comment: Somebody know if -Dlogback.configurationFile is the right synthax for Tomcat 9-Java8 application?